# Uniform continuity and boundedness in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

> For bounded subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$, uniform continuity of $f:E\to \mathbb R$ implies boundedness of $f(E)$.

the proof is pretty simple. take $\epsilon=1$. then there exist $\delta$ such that 
$$|x-y|<\delta\quad \to\quad |f(x)-f(y)|<1$$
Since E is bounded, we can cover E with finitely many $\delta$-balls.
so we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<$ (The number of $\delta$-balls) for any $x,y \in E$.

If the function is defined on metric space $(X,d)$ to metric space $(Y,\rho)$ instead of $E$ and $\mathbb R$, is the corresponding theorem still true?

---

Edit:

> Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be metric spaces and $(X,d)$ is bounded. if $f : X \to Y$ is uniform continuous, is $f(X)$ bounded in $Y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

What makes it hold in $\Bbb R$ is the precompactness (or more informatively, total boundedness) of bounded sets, which no longer holds in general metric spaces.

Let's consider an arbitrary infinite *discrete* metric space, then the space is bounded itself and *any* function defined on it is uniformly continuous, but of course needn't be bounded.